# vue3+vite npm The plugin path is the previous plugin with the same name

Tags: npm, vuejs3, node-modules, vite

In page.vue:

```
import 'vue-cropper/dist/index.css

import { VueCropper }  from "vue-cropper"
```

I want use @vue-cropper

node modoules:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkaot.png)

Because the previous deleted plugin @shn-vue-ui I used and its name was also vue_cropper, it somehow pointed to shn_vue_ui:

```
[vite] error while updating dependencies:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\code\javacode\Web\MyNote\mynote-page\node_modules\_shn-vue-ui@1.3.19-gac@shn-vue-ui\lib\shn-vue-ui.umd.min.js
```

I've tried:

```
npm clean cache --force
```

don't work